# Calling ActionBarActivity from Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbaractivity

I am working on an Android app and I have created 2 fragments (FragmentA, FragmentB) I also have Adapter of fragment activities and mymain class. The problem is that I want to populate those 2 fragments with data that I have recieved with webservices in my 2 action bar activities( a table and a pie chart). How can I convert the following Pie Chart into Fragment Activity?

```
public class PieChartActivity extends Details implements OnSeekBarChangeListener,OnChartValueSelectedListener {
    private PieChart mChart;
    private SeekBar mSeekBarX, mSeekBarY;
    private TextView tvX, tvY;

    private Typeface tf;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_piechart);

        mSeekBarX = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.sbPieChart);
        mSeekBarY = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar2);
        mSeekBarY.setProgress(10);


        mSeekBarX.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
        mSeekBarY.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);

        mChart = (PieChart) findViewById(R.id.chart1);
        mChart.setUsePercentValues(true);

        // change the color of the center-hole
        // mChart.setHoleColor(Color.rgb(235, 235, 235));
        mChart.setHoleColorTransparent(true);

        tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "OpenSans-Regular.ttf");

        mChart.setCenterTextTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "OpenSans-Light.ttf"));

        mChart.setHoleRadius(60f);
        mChart.setDescription("");
        mChart.setDrawCenterText(true);
        mChart.setDrawHoleEnabled(true);
        mChart.setRotationAngle(0);

        // enable rotation of the chart by touch
        mChart.setRotationEnabled(true);

        // mChart.setUnit(" €");
        // mChart.setDrawUnitsInChart(true);

        // add a selection listener
        mChart.setOnChartValueSelectedListener(this);
        // mChart.setTouchEnabled(false);

        mChart.setCenterText("MPAndroidChart\nLibrary");

        setData(3, 100);

        mChart.animateXY(1500, 1500);
        // mChart.spin(2000, 0, 360);

        Legend l = mChart.getLegend();
        l.setPosition(LegendPosition.RIGHT_OF_CHART);
        l.setXEntrySpace(7f);
        l.setYEntrySpace(5f);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.actionToggleValues: {
                for (DataSet<?> set : mChart.getData().getDataSets())
                    set.setDrawValues(!set.isDrawValuesEnabled());

                mChart.invalidate();
                break;
            }
            case R.id.actionToggleHole: {
                if (mChart.isDrawHoleEnabled())
                    mChart.setDrawHoleEnabled(false);
                else
                    mChart.setDrawHoleEnabled(true);
                mChart.invalidate();
                break;
            }
            case R.id.actionDrawCenter: {
                if (mChart.isDrawCenterTextEnabled())
                    mChart.setDrawCenterText(false);
                else
                    mChart.setDrawCenterText(true);
                mChart.invalidate();
                break;
            }
            case R.id.actionToggleXVals: {

                mChart.setDrawSliceText(!mChart.isDrawSliceTextEnabled());
                mChart.invalidate();
                break;
            }
            case R.id.actionSave: {
                // mChart.saveToGallery("title"+System.currentTimeMillis());
                mChart.saveToPath("title" + System.currentTimeMillis(), "");
                break;
            }
            case R.id.actionTogglePercent:
                mChart.setUsePercentValues(!mChart.isUsePercentValuesEnabled());
                mChart.invalidate();
                break;
            case R.id.animateX: {
                mChart.animateX(1800);
                break;
            }
            case R.id.animateY: {
                mChart.animateY(1800);
                break;
            }
            case R.id.animateXY: {
                mChart.animateXY(1800, 1800);
                break;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

//        tvX.setText("" + (mSeekBarX.getProgress() + 1));
  //      tvY.setText("" + (mSeekBarY.getProgress()));

        setData(mSeekBarX.getProgress(), mSeekBarY.getProgress());
    }

    private void setData(int count, float range) {


        String[] mParties= Details.vls;
        String title = Details.title;

        mSeekBarX.setMax(mParties.length - 1);

        float mult = range;

        ArrayList<Entry> yVals1 = new ArrayList<Entry>();

        // IMPORTANT: In a PieChart, no values (Entry) should have the same
        // xIndex (even if from different DataSets), since no values can be
        // drawn above each other.
       int sum = 0;
       for (int i = 0; i < count + 1 ; i++) {
           sum = sum + Integer.parseInt(mParties[i].replaceAll("[\\D]", ""));

       }

        for (int i = 0; i < count + 1; i++) {
            int dd =  Integer.parseInt(mParties[i].replaceAll("[\\D]", ""));
            yVals1.add(new Entry((float) ( dd * 100), i));
        }


        ArrayList<String> xVals = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (int i = 0; i < count + 1; i++)
        xVals.add(mParties[i % mParties.length]);

        PieDataSet dataSet = new PieDataSet(yVals1, title);
        dataSet.setSliceSpace(3f);

        // add a lot of colors

        ArrayList<Integer> colors = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for (int c : ColorTemplate.VORDIPLOM_COLORS)
            colors.add(c);

        for (int c : ColorTemplate.JOYFUL_COLORS)
            colors.add(c);

        for (int c : ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS)
            colors.add(c);

        for (int c : ColorTemplate.LIBERTY_COLORS)
            colors.add(c);

        for (int c : ColorTemplate.PASTEL_COLORS)
            colors.add(c);

        colors.add(ColorTemplate.getHoloBlue());

        dataSet.setColors(colors);

        PieData data = new PieData(xVals, dataSet);
        data.setValueFormatter(new PercentFormatter());
        data.setValueTextSize(11f);
        data.setValueTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        data.setValueTypeface(tf);
        mChart.setData(data);

        // undo all highlights
        mChart.highlightValues(null);

        mChart.invalidate();
    }
```

Comment: You will do it the same way as normal activity class. If you want to populate data in fragment you need to transfer data from activity to fragment. I still don't understand your question

Comment: Do you mean this? `((ActionBarActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();` in `onActivityCreated()`

Comment: @Skizo public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_piechart,container,false);

        ((PieChartActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
    }

Comment: @arual `onActivityCreated()` ! :)

Comment: @Skizo I added my fragment in question. pls modify it because I am not getting your answer

Comment: @Skizo anyway it doesn't solve my issue. How to convert PieChart Activity into fragment?

Comment: *Unclear what you are asking*

Comment: @Skizo my problem is that I want the pie chart into my tab, but I have the pie chart as activity. How to convert it as fragment? I am posting my class at my question. Pls take a look. Because even if I start the activity at fragment it doesnt solve the issue

Comment: If you are really wondering about how to convert an Activity to a Fragment, I very strongly recommend you read an actual book about Android framework before going anywhere with your app...

Answer (score 2):

@arual You can do this by casting Activity class into ActionbarActivity class as this way.

```
((ActionBarActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
```